# how can i change the default css property of a sample sencha touch application

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch-2.1

This is my css code.
I added this css code in MyApp/resources/sass/stylesheet/app.scss

```
.dataview-item{
   width : 33.33%;
   height : 50%;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
   border-bottom: 5px solid #59535E;
   float:left;   
   padding:2px;
}

.arHeadline{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family: 'Museo Sans';
    color: #66ab16;
}
.arbyline{
    font-size:10px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-family: 'Museo Sans';
}
```

I also implemented the above css in view block as follows :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyContainer', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',

config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'dataview',
            height: '100%',
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            width: '100%',
            layout: {
                type: 'fit'
            },
            inline: {
                wrap: true
            },
            itemCls: 'dataview-item',
            itemTpl: [
                '<div class="arHeadline">',
                '    {Headline}',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="arbyline">',
                '    {Author}',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="arcontent">',
                '    {Content}',
                '</div>'
            ],
            store: 'articlestore'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Summary'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Then in command line I typed the following commands:

```
$ cd MyApp/resources/sass/

$ compass watch ./
```

but still I am getting only title bar on output no change in the css. Can any one can help me to change the default CSS and add the above mentioned CSS?

[the blog I referred](http://sureshdotariya.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-display-dataview-component-in.html)

Comment: just try compass watch , you are already in sass folder and try to clear cache and start browser